# Getting Reorder to ignore stock levels in magento

Tags: php, magento, cart

i've been tasked to create a system where a customer can edit an order before it reaches the processing stage, i figure that the easiest way is to use the cart but with some edits to it to detect that your editing the order rather than making a new one

i have been testing out theories so far and everything seem to pan out, on theory i have been trying to get to work is utilizing the same process for re-ordering to populate the cart with the previous order, however i've ran into a problem, if an item is out of stock, it wont be added and until the customer confirms the changed to their order, i can go and release what they ordered, i can store how much the customer ordered but only if the item is added to the cart

so is there a way to get magento to add items to the cart with the re-order while ignoring what stock levels are

EDIT:

i've tried removing the Try Catch in `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract` in the function `reorderAction()` and it's adding the items however this means also i can't catch the exception of it's if it's just a notice or if there is any other reason why it can't add the item to the cart besides not having the stock

Comment: I am sure that there is a way.  What have you tried?

Comment: at the moment i'm just editing the original re-order to add all items regardless of stock but when `$cart->addOrderItem($item);` is called magento throws a `Mage_Core_Exception` exception so the default magento functionality is always checking, i can't think of any other way that doesn't result in my just coding up a sql query and i've been advised to have it as the last resort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now, the trick was to enable Backorders and also modify parts of magento to prevent sellers from exceeding stock levels when they normally order (since if an item only has 6 in stock, with backorders enabled a customer can buy 10), after that it was simply setting up a system in the cart to detect when your editing an order and only allow backordering there since all orders are checked in the warehouse